# using Python to create mediaWiki pages

Tags: python, shell, mediawiki

Just brainstorming at work, and thought that a tool that took all our shell utilities and put their --help documentation online would be useful.

Is there a py module or does anyone have any advice for using python to auto create pages in a mediaWiki?

Thanks!

Comment: if the data in your --help documentation is structured, it might be easier to just write a mini-parser or mini-set of regular expressions and use that to convert your documentation to MediaWiki format.  I can't imagine you'd be using that many mediawiki features to convert your documentation, so it might be easier to keep things simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PyWikipediaBot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPywikipediabot) may be what you're looking for.

Internally, it interacts with the MediaWiki API. You can get information on that by accessing "api.php" on your wiki install (or by looking at another install's api.php: e.g, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php).

Comment: Thanks. That looks pretty useful. I'll dive through it.